# How to make a mysql "ladder" queries in nodejs with express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm having a problem, when I want to make a queries in "ladder" form with nodejs, express and mysql and return one json, It don't works for me, the structure of I want to make is:

```
select dev_id*,dev_name from devices
select cont_id*, cont_name from controllers where dev_id = dev_id
select act_id, acti_id from actions where cont_id = cont_id**

return json({devices,{controller,{actions}}})
```

I'm using forEach function and also I trying to use callback function.

Comment: What do you mean by ladder queries? What does `dev_id*` and `cont_id**` mean?

Comment: `where dev_id = dev_id` is true for every row.

Comment: It seems like you just need to join all 3 tables.

Comment: Hi Barman, join all 3 tables is possible when I have a row with multiple values? I have 3 tables with many values associates, I need to nested queries to get a json, in php and sails.js I did can to get with for cycle, but with nodejs and express I can't.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, Barman, I just saw her, I will go to test, when I tested It, I will write to you, thank you, I have 4 days with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all 3 tables, then loop through the results and build nested objects.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});
var sql = `SELECT d.dev_id, d.dev_name, c.cont_id, c.cont_name, a.act_id, a.acti_id
           FROM devices AS d
           LEFT JOIN controllers AS c ON c.dev_id = c.dev_id
           LEFT JOIN actions AS a ON a.cont_id = c.cont_id`;
con.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    conn.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var devices = {};
        $result.forEach(({dev_id, dev_name, cont_id, cont_name, act_id, acti_id}) => {
            devices[dev_id] = devices[dev_id] || {id: dev_id, name: dev_name, controllers: {}};
            devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id] = devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id] || {id: cont_id, name: cont_name, actions: {}};
            devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id].actions[act_id] = {id: act_id, acti_id: acti_id};
        });
    });
    // do something with devices here
});
```

Remember that all the mysql query code is asynchronous, so you can't return values normally. You need to use callbacks or promises.

The `devices` variable will look like:

```
{
    devid1: {
        id: "devid1",
        name: "devname1",
        controllers: {
            contid1: {
                id: "contid1",
                name: "contname1",
                actions: {
                    actionid1: {
                        id: "actionid1",
                        acti_id: "acti_id1"
                    },
                    actionid2: {
                        id: "actionid2",
                        acti_id: "acti_id2"
                    }
                }
            },
            contid2: {
                id: "contid2",
                name: "contname2",
                actions: {
                    actionid3: {
                        id: "actionid3",
                        acti_id: "acti_id3"
                    }
                }
            }
        |
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barman, I'm testing your  code, the sql is working, but the last part generate an error : var devices = {};
        $result.forEach({dev_id, dev_name, cont_id, cont_name, act_id, acti_id} => {
            devices[dev_id] = devices[dev_id] || {id: dev_id, name: dev_name, controlllers: {}};
            devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id] = devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id] || {id: cont_id, name: cont_name, actions: {}};
            devices[dev_id].controllers[cont_id].actions[act_id] = {id: act_id, acti_id: acti_id};
        });

Comment: I see, I need parentheses around the destructing argument in the arrow function.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I'm trying to test your code, but It generate me this error:   result.forEach(({device_id,device_name,device_controller_id,device_controller_name,action_id,action_name}) => {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: What version of node.js are you running? That's ES6 destructuring syntax, older versions don't support it.

Comment: V5.12.0, I should to change to 8?

Comment: Yes. ES6 features were added in V6.

Comment: Ok, I upgrade my node version, but It generate other error:  /Users/domoteco/grafeno/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined  in  devices[device_id].controllers[device_controller_id] = devices[device_id].controllers[device_controller_id] || {device_controller_id: device_controller_id, device_controller_name: device_controller_name, actions: {}};

Comment: I had a typo `controlllers:`.

Comment: This are the complete values :   var devices = {};
results.forEach(({device_id,device_name,device_controller_id,device_controller_name,action_id,action_name}) => {devices[device_id] = devices[device_id] || {device_id: device_id, device_name: device_name, controlllers: {}};devices[device_id].controllers[device_controller_id] = devices[device_id].controllers[device_controller_id] || {device_controller_id: device_controller_id, device_controller_name: device_controller_name, actions: {}};

Comment: devices[device_id].controllers[device_controller_id].actions[action_id] = {action_id: action_id, action_name: action_name};});